# SSD not shown in My Computer

Tags: ssd, windows-8.1

I have a 24GB SSD, and isn't being shown in My Computer. I looked it up in Disk Management and found it, but it says the SSD is a primary partition. I tried to format it but there is only "Help" on the right-click menu.

In Task Manager, on the "Performance" tab, the SSD is Disk 1, at the bottom of the page, it says "Formatted: 0 MB".

I noticed that the SSD doesn't have an assigned drive letter.

How do I format the SSD?

Comment: Did you right click the disk space or the grey panel to the left of the disk... The part that says "Disk 1"

Comment: @BigChris Yes, and I've also right-clicked the rectangle with a small blue bar, it displays "Help" only.

Comment: Follow this link top instructions: http://www.jwgoerlich.us/blogengine/post/2009/11/05/Use-Diskpart-to-Create-and-Format-Partitions.aspx - id is your SSD number... letter is the drive letter you want to assign.

Comment: @BigChris WOW I followed the instructions and it worked like a charm! Thank you very much, now if you'd like to answer the question so I can tick it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open an elevated command prompt and type the items highlighted:

`Diskpart`

DISKPART> `list disk`
DISKPART> `select disk (id)`
DISKPART> `online disk` (if the disk is not online)
DISKPART> `attributes disk clear readonly`
DISKPART> `clean`
DISKPART> `convert mbr` (or gpt)
DISKPART> `create partition primary`
DISKPART> `select part 1`
DISKPART> `active` (if this is the boot partition)
DISKPART> `format fs=ntfs label=(name) quick`
DISKPART> `assign letter (letter)`
DISKPART> `list volume`

Where:

(id) = the disk number of your SSD
(name) = the volume label you want
(letter) = the drive letter you want to assign

Source: http://www.jwgoerlich.us/blogengine/post/2009/11/05/Use-Diskpart-to-Create-and-Format-Partitions.aspx

Comment: I'm on mobile... Does someone mind tidying this up pleeeeease :) Thank you!